# MySQL Query to fetch Distinct Rows with latest status

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, namely - areas, works and jobs.

```
areas             works              jobs
-----             -----              -----
area_id           work_id            area_id (FK)
area_name         task               work_id (FK)
area_type         app_area           status
                                     updated_at
```

I'm trying to select the total list of areas cross joined with works such that I have all the permutations for areas vs works, then have the LATEST status of that combination, if it exists. I want distinct rows for each area_id-work_id combination.

I put together the below query statement but some rows have statuses displayed as NULL when they actually exist. My guess is there's something wrong with my inner SELECT statement but try as I may, I could not get it to work, any idea what's wrong with my statement?

```
SELECT area_name, works.task, jobs.status
FROM areas
CROSS JOIN works ON works.work_id = works.work_id
LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.status = (SELECT jobs.status FROM jobs ORDER BY jobs.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) AND 
(jobs.work_id = works.work_id AND jobs.area_id = areas.area_id)
WHERE works.app_area = 'zone' AND areas.area_type = 'zone'
ORDER BY areas.area_id, works.work_id, jobs.updated_at;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for the last status should be using the *date* not the *status*.  The logic looks like this:

```
SELECT a.area_name, w.task, j.status
FROM areas a CROSS JOIN
     works w LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON j.work_id = w.work_id AND j.area_id = a.area_id AND
        j.updated_at = (SELECT MAX(j2.updated_at)
                        FROM jobs j2
                        WHERE j2.work_id = w.work_id AND j2.area_id = a.area_id
                       )
WHERE w.app_area = 'zone' AND a.area_type = 'zone'
ORDER BY a.area_id, w.work_id, j.updated_at;
```

This also fixes some other problems, such as having an `ON` clause with `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Gordon, shouldn't the j.updated = be in the where clause?

Comment: @henry . . . No.  That would undermine the `left join`.  Normally, I would do this with another subquery, but the OP had the subquery in the `on` clause so I followed that style.

Comment: Gordon, I think your MAX(j.updated) should be MAX(j2.updated)

Comment: minor typo j.updated_at but other than that it works great! Thanks @GordonLinoff!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it by your own query then please replace this line in the left join sub query

```
SELECT j.status FROM jobs j ORDER BY   jobs.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Gordon Solution, I think this is another way you can do it. you'll have to test to see which way works faster for you.

```
SELECT a.area_name, w.task, (SELECT MAX(j2.updated_at)
                     FROM jobs j2
                     WHERE j2.work_id = w.work_id AND j2.area_id = a.area_id
                    ) status
FROM areas a CROSS JOIN
     works w LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON j.work_id = w.work_id AND j.area_id = a.area_id 
WHERE w.app_area = 'zone' AND a.area_type = 'zone'
ORDER BY a.area_id, w.work_id, j.updated_at;
```